# How to modify Powerpoint with Office.Js APIs

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm looking for Office.js Powerpoint add-in apis that can modify slide content properties (e.g. change all font to Calibri).

The .load() and .sync() methods to read properties (font size , color, position) of ppt content are not documented very clearly and I could not find the list of options that can be passed to the .load() method in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.slide?view=powerpoint-js-preview#load_propertyNames_)

eg: calling .load("slides") along with the .sync() loads the slides property.

context.presentation.load("slides");
await context.sync();
I'm looking for all the possible arguments of the load() methods, and all the different properties that I can fetch.

Answer (score 0):

We have been adding APIs to the PowerPoint-specific JavaScript library, but we don't yet have the detailed content modification you're looking for.

There is a guidance article about `load` and `sync` (among other things) at [Using the application-specific API model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model). For a good understanding of these methods, I also recommend [Building Office Add-ins with Office.js](https://buildingofficeaddins.com/).

You can add content to PowerPoint with the Office Common APIs. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office) for the distinction between the Common and application-specific libraries and links to more information.

Comment: Hey Rick, [Using the application-specific API mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-mode) is throwing 404